# intercepting events over iframe

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I am experimenting using a transparent div over an iframe (not same origin) to catch events. I can catch the events with a transparent div over the iframe, but is there a way to let events get to iframe, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There is only one target to an event, if you have a div in front of the iframe then it will be the target and it will never reach the iframe.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible but was wondering if there was some trick

Answer (score 0):

In case a messaging between frames from different domains could solve your problem check out PortHole - http://ternarylabs.github.com/porthole/

It will require you to have access to both domains -- there's a proxy file to be uploaded on both domains. Otherwise it won't work.